# EOF while reading packet - connection failed

Tags: sftp, eof

I use cyberduck for SFTP my website files to the server. Dreamhost is the server.

In setting up a new bookmark in cyberduck I received this error "Connection failed - EOF while reading packet." [end of file]

The website is up and working fine, http://ce-t.org

Initially I thought this error had to do with the connection opening with cyberduck. So I setup a different bookmark to test and was able to do without a problem.

I have also deleted my first attempt to setup and reset up. This did not alter anything.

Now after doing more reading, may be in one of the website files?

As you can see i am a novice.

Help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File transfer through sockets, final size with less bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684733/file-transfer-through-sockets-final-size-with-less-bytes)

Comment: This has been resolved. The error corrected after changing a setting on the server host.

Comment: For those of us also encountering this problem, perhaps you might share *which* setting?

Answer (score 7):

Usually when I run into this issue, its because my pw has expired.

Try SSHing into the server and change/update your pw. After I change it, I can FTP in.

Answer (score 5):

This is 3 years too late for the OP. But I had this error when trying to make an SFTP connection to hosting on a Plesk server and the solution was to:

**Enable the 'Access to the server over SSH' setting** for the ftp user via the Plesk Control panel.

Of course you might need to contact your hosting service to get this done if you are not managing your own server.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the same error occurred due to a syntax error in the `.bashrc` file on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the default account setting for an FTP user at Dreamhost might specify an FTP connection. If so, trying to use Cyberduck to connect via SFTP will generate this error message. You can use the Dreamhost control panel to edit the user's record to specify SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have used dropbear ssh server.
I replace this server with openssh server, and now i can open the sftp connection without any issues.