# Some content of the binary file missing after receiving from client

Tags: c, linux, sockets, android-ndk

[enter image description here][1]I have searched for the solution but none of those worked for me, can someone help me in understanding where I might have done wrong or something which I have misunderstood and not handled properly in my code.

For example the size of the file supposed to be received was 3656713 and the actual size received on the server is 3656464.

In my code BUFFER_SIZE is a macro and it is set to 4096, I think it does not matter because I have tried with different numbers like 256, 1024 etc,

I have attached both client and server code.

This is client which is sending media file:

```
    while(1){
        //char buff[BUFFER_SIZE]={0};
        memset(buff, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        while(!feof(fp)){
            int nread = fread(buff, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native", "%d nread %d\n", ++i, nread);
            if(nread == 0){
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native", "Something went wrong while reading the file");
                break;
            }
            if(nread > 0){
                int totalWritten = 0;
                do {
                    int actualWritten;
                    actualWritten = write (sockfd, buff + totalWritten, nread - totalWritten);
                    //actualWritten = send (sockfd, buff + totalWritten, nread - totalWritten, 0);
                    if( actualWritten == - 1 ) {
                        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native", "Unable to write to socket \n");
                        finalStatus = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    totalWritten += actualWritten;
                } while( totalWritten < nread );
            }
            memset(buff, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            //usleep(2);
        }
        if(feof(fp)){
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native", "End of the file reached");
            EOFReached = true;
            fclose(fp);
        }
        if(ferror(fp)){
            fclose(fp);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native", "Something went wrong while reading the file content");
        }
        break;
    }
```

This is server which is receiving the media file:

```
 buffer = (char *)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
 while((bytesReceived = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0){
     receivedBytes = receivedBytes + bytesReceived;
     printf("%d : Actual size : %d Received size : %d\n", ++i, actualSizeOfTheFile, receivedBytes);
     if(strncmp(buffer, "MYNEWSTRANSFERCOMPLETE", 22) == 0){
         fclose(fp);
         printf("Closed the file as server received the command : %s\n", buffer);
         break;
     }else{
         //printf("%d Bytes recived %d and the data is %s\n", ++i, bytesReceived, buffer);
         fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesReceived, fp);
     }
     memset(buffer, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE);
 }
 printf("Final string received from client is %s\n", buffer);
 memset(buffer, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE);
 printf("Total bytes received from client is :::::%d", receivedBytes);
 if((bytesReceived = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0){
     printf("Final string received from client is %s\n", buffer);
     if((write(sockfd, "You can close the socket", 24)) > 0){
         printf("Acknowledging the client to confirming for closing the connection\n");
     }else{
         printf("Unable to acknowledge the client on close confirmation of the connection\n");
     }
 }else{
     printf("Socket might have been closed by the client\n\n");
 }
```

My problem is I am trying to transfer media file from Android client to Linux server over sockets using 'C'. Earlier when I started with simple file write and read the media file received and played without any issues.

But all of sudden I see some data being missed in the final received file on the Linux server.

As I am unable to add the screen shots pasting the log statements here`

Client Log

05-15 18:59:08.072 30084-30084/com.example.user.resumablesample I/Native: 889 nread 4096
05-15 18:59:08.072 30084-30084/com.example.user.resumablesample I/Native: totalWritten : 4096 out of nread 4096
05-15 18:59:08.072 30084-30084/com.example.user.resumablesample I/Native: 890 nread 4096
05-15 18:59:08.072 30084-30084/com.example.user.resumablesample I/Native: totalWritten : 4096 out of nread 4096
05-15 18:59:08.072 30084-30084/com.example.user.resumablesample I/Native: 891 nread 4096
05-15 18:59:08.072 30084-30084/com.example.user.resumablesample I/Native: totalWritten : 4096 out of nread 4096
05-15 18:59:08.072 30084-30084/com.example.user.resumablesample I/Native: 892 nread 4096
05-15 18:59:08.072 30084-30084/com.example.user.resumablesample I/Native: totalWritten : 4096 out of nread 4096
05-15 18:59:08.072 30084-30084/com.example.user.resumablesample I/Native: 893 nread 3081
05-15 18:59:08.072 30084-30084/com.example.user.resumablesample I/Native: totalWritten : 3081 out of nread 3081
05-15 18:59:08.072 30084-30084/com.example.user.resumablesample I/Native: End of the file reached
05-15 19:04:22.387 30084-30094/com.example.user.resumablesample W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.375ms

Server Log

2513 : Actual size : 3656713 Received size : 3644423 Received bytes : 1408
2514 : Actual size : 3656713 Received size : 3645831 Received bytes : 1408
2515 : Actual size : 3656713 Received size : 3647239 Received bytes : 1408
2516 : Actual size : 3656713 Received size : 3648647 Received bytes : 1408
2517 : Actual size : 3656713 Received size : 3650055 Received bytes : 1408
2518 : Actual size : 3656713 Received size : 3651463 Received bytes : 1408
2519 : Actual size : 3656713 Received size : 3652871 Received bytes : 1408
2520 : Actual size : 3656713 Received size : 3654279 Received bytes : 1408
2521 : Actual size : 3656713 Received size : 3655687 Received bytes : 1408
2522 : Actual size : 3656713 Received size : 3656464 Received bytes : 777

File listing on the sever
-rw-r--r-- 1 magic_ramana magic_ramana 3653632 May 15 13:29 mynews_4zUIgxb5nh1494854941443.mp4
`
I observer that the last chunk 3081Bytes which client log says has been transferred, but the same amount of data is missing in the final file which I have listed. Final file size is 3653632, but that suppose to be 3656713 which is 3081 bytes more that suppose to be transferred in the last chunk

Comment: By the way before asking this question I have tried below links which did not help me muchhttp://www.binarytides.com/receive-full-data-with-recv-socket-function-in-c/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684733/file-transfer-through-sockets-final-size-with-less-bytes

Comment: What do you do with the socket after you send the data?

Comment: You don't need any of these `memset()` calls, and if you think you do it indicates a bug elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @rici, On client side after sending the data(means once the EOF reaches) closing the file and the socket descriptors.

Comment: @EJP: disabled the memset() calls, still same issue

Comment: As I didn't claim the `memset()`s were causing the problem, that's not surprising.

Comment: Even if the memset() was required, (which it is not, as EJP states), it's in the wrong place.

Comment: @SunilYerra when you ran the server under your debugger, what did you find out?

Comment: Also, you have some prinf() calls that describe progress.  Unfortunately, you have denied us this output listing for some reason:(

Comment: Sorry for delay in response, I have disabled and changed the code.
So took some time to code the log which I published in this thread. Any way please fine the below log from client and server respectively.

Comment: I have provided the log information, sorry if that is confusing, I m new to post questions in this portal. By the way my observation was client log says 3081 Bytes transferred in that final chunk, but same amount of data is missing in the final file received at the server. File transferred is of 3656713 bytes, file received is of 3653632 which is 3081 bytes less in size which is exactly the chunk of bytes being transferred in the last write on socket. But with having proper understanding on which line of code is stopping that to transfer i am unable to figure out the logic issue please help

Comment: this line: `while(!feof(fp)){` is NEVER correct.  The function: `feof()` does not do what you seem to think it does.   suggest: `while( 0 < ( nread = fread( buff, 1, buffer_size, fp ) ) ) {`  Note: if `fread()` returns 0 then use `feof()` and/or `ferror()` to determine if the 0 was EOF or an error event.

Comment: note: the function: `fread()` returns a `size_t` not an `int`

Comment: note: the function: `write()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `int`

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions and samples. Those helped me in understanding the TCP sockets bit more.

But i have solved the issue by introducing a separate socket only for file transfer, earlier I was using the same socket for sending the initial information like FILE Size, File name etc., but now I am closing the first socket after sending the file size and initial info, then I am opening another socket for sending the file ... it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strncmp(buffer, "MYNEWSTRANSFERCOMPLETE", 22) == 0){
```

The problem is here. You cannot rely on receiving this as the first thing and the only thing in the buffer. TCP is a streaming protocol and can deliver the data to the receiving application any way it likes, including one byte at a time, or coalescing buffers, or anything in between, as long as it delivers all the data exactly once and in the right order.

I will also note that you aren't actually *sending* this string anywhere.

Similarly

```
if((write(sockfd, "You can close the socket", 24)) > 0){
```

and all such cannot be guaranteed to be received discretely. I will also note that you aren't actually *receiving* this data anywhere.

You will either have to transmit the file size ahead of the file, or close the socket after you've sent the file without using any kind of application protocol.

Comment: Hi EJP, 

I have edited the code as you suggested, removed all the application specific protocol checks, but again end up with same issue. I have sent the file size ahead of the actual transfer, then started the transfer. On server side checking if the bytes received are matching with file size, else reading the socket.

Comment: I have removed all the application specific protocol checks and simply reading for the whole content to receive at the server end.
After reaching the EOF on the client then closing the file and socket..

No luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not set the `SO_LINGER` socket option, closing the socket will discard queued data which has not been sent. I suspect that is what is happening here.

Comment: I dont see any difference after setting SO_LINGER, by the way thanks for the info I never knew about this.

Comment: In that case, I guess it's time to haul out a packetsniffer  like www.wireshark.org and see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the following code excerpts do not depend on some 'adhoc' text being transmitted by the client to the server to indicate the transfer is complete.

here are the needed corrections for the client code

```
bool finalStatus = true;
size_t nread;
while( 0 < (nread = fread(buff, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) ) )
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native", "%d nread %d\n", ++i, nread);        

    int totalWritten = 0;
    do
    {
        ssize_t actualWritten;
        actualWritten = write (sockfd, buff + totalWritten, (ssize_t)nread - totalWritten);
        //actualWritten = send (sockfd, buff + totalWritten, nread - totalWritten, 0);
        if( actualWritten == - 1 )
        {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native", "Unable to write to socket \n");
            finalStatus = false;
            break;
        }
        totalWritten += actualWritten;
    } while( totalWritten < nread && finalStatus);
}

if( !nread )
{
    if(feof(fp))
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native", "End of the file reached");
        EOFReached = true;;
    }

    else if(ferror(fp))
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native", "Something went wrong while reading the file content");
    }
}

fclose(fp);
```

here are the needed corrections for the server code

```
buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
if( !buffer )
{
    perror( "malloc failed" );
    close( sockfd );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, malloc successful

int i = 0;
ssize_t receivedBytes = 0;
ssize_t bytesReceived;
while((bytesReceived = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
{
    receivedBytes = receivedBytes + bytesReceived;
    printf("%d : Actual size : %ld Received size : %ld\n", ++i, actualSizeOfTheFile, receivedBytes);
}

if( !bytesReceived )
{
    printf( "EOF reached\n" );
}

else if( 0 > bytesReceived )
{
    perror( "read failed" );
}

close( sockfd );

printf("Total bytes received from client is :::::%ld", receivedBytes);
```